# How to set up eclipse with GWT and (regular servlet) Jetty backend

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jetty

Does anybody know how to set up a project in Eclipse with GWT and a jetty backend (regular web app, not app engine)? Or know of a good link (tried googling it, but no dice)

I've been trying to set up this all evening, but just ran into a number of strange problems, some seems to be bugs in WST/Jetty and the other is that the host page just doesn't work :-(

Comment: Are you using Google Plugin for Eclipse? It's kind of straight-forward :S

Comment: yup... latest version, on Eclipse Indigo

Comment: By jetty backend, you mean your own jetty server and not the one provided by GWT with devmode?

Comment: Yes... My own server running Jetty, running in eclipse as a server via the Jetty server plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to run your own jetty server together with GWT.

If you run your own jetty server you have to invoke dev-mode in GWT with the `-noserver`parameter or for solution one you can use `-server JettyLauncher`

1. Use your own `JettyLauncher.class` or use [gwt-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-jetty/).
2. Use [Jetty maven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) to launch the jetty server (see [here](http://techeyes.blogspot.com/2007/06/up-and-running-with-gwt-and-maven-2.html) and [here](http://missinglinkblog.com/2011/03/02/gwt-and-maven-jetty-plugin/) for infos)
3. Use [Jetty WTP plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin) for eclipse to start a jetty server.

I personally used solution 3 (Jetty WTP plugin) to start a custom Jetty 7 server for my GWT project and it works fine.

Comment: I use WTP, but there seems to be a number of bugs, when my app is run via WTP the WAR is copied to a temp directory somewhere under <Workspacefolder>/.plugins, but the automatic sync'ing did not work well. Solved it by just redeploying, but it is a bit of a hassle... plus there were a few things I had to set in project properties... but for now it works fine...

Comment: I followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven

It works fine. If I change resource files the WTP plugin automatically re-publishes them and it works without a server restart. Only if I change servlet mapping or other internal stuff I have to restart it.

Comment: Well, of some reason my setup doesn't republish static files, just the compiled ones... wierd... might send in a bug report on that one...