# How to debug a GWT application using an external server

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I need help to run/debug my GWT application on an external server and **not** using the default jetty server.
I read several related topics to that question, e.g.

- [Where to write GWT -noserver option to avoid jetty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678662/where-to-write-gwt-noserver-option-to-avoid-jetty)
- [How to set up eclipse with GWT and (regular servlet) Jetty backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199722/how-to-set-up-eclipse-with-gwt-and-regular-servlet-jetty-backend?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Is it possible to debug GWT client code on a REMOTE server using IntelliJ 9 Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629297/is-it-possible-to-debug-gwt-client-code-on-a-remote-server-using-intellij-9-comm)
- http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html

and the overall-conclusion is to

- add parameter -noserver (either directly or using the google plugin for eclipse)
- specify the URL of the desired server within the arguments-tab of the run/debug configuration

in run/debug configuration for a webApplication.

But after doing this, for me it seems that still the default jetty server is tried to be invoked by the provided launch URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/ApplicationName.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Of course, the server can not be started due to the -noserver flag, but **why** is it tried to launch at all?

When following the GWT-guide:

- Configure your server however you need to; note the URL which contains the host page for your GWT application.
- .......
- Add the -noserver command line argument. Change the URL at the end of the argument list to match the URL you recorded in step #1.

How do I change the URL at the end of the argument list? In my project, there is no URL at the end of the argument list which looks like:

-noserver -nosuperDevMode -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -war C:...\MyWebApp\war com.mycompany.mywebapp.MyWebApp

Which flag do I use to specify the URL of the desired server, -bindAddress, -server, -startupUrl?

Is my assumption correct, that after proper configuration the provided launch URL must not contain any 127.0.0.1, but (only) the URL of the dedicated server?

Any tipps are very welcome - I'm rather confused at the moment.
Best Regards!

Comment: what GWT and GWT Plugin version are you using?

Comment: GWT: 2.7.0

Google Plugin for Eclipse: 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r44

Answer (score 0):

First: The URL that is shown after starting the devmode is just for your convenience(the jetty code server was not started).
You can check that by starting the devmode and then opening the URL to your external server, for example `http://localhost:8888/your_app_path/index.html`, add just add `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`. Usually the devmode should start now anyway.

By setting up the startup url to `http://localhost:8888/your_app_path/index.html` the plugin will show you the correct URL: `http://localhost:8888/your_app_path/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the best options is to run the GWT Development Mode (CodeServer) instead of DevMode with -noServer to debug with an external web server.

Example of Using a WTP runtime configuration with a GWT Development Mode with Codeserver
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtH4KzmguL0&index=7&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT&ab_channel=BrandonDonnelson

Example of using a Simple external web server with GWT Development Mode (CodeServer)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOwUpBuVtWE&index=5&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT&ab_channel=BrandonDonnelson